# How do those who believe Jesus was eternally the Son explain Jesus being chosen?

Tags: exegesis, trinity, christology, gospel-of-luke

Luke 9:35 is

> And a voice came from the cloud, saying, “This is My Son, whom **I have
> chosen**. Listen to Him!”

The concept of 'choosing' entails a chronological sequence of events, where one is initially *not* chosen, and then *is* chosen.

For Christians who believe Jesus was eternally begotten as the Son, how do they explain the idea that the Father *chose* Jesus?

Comment: jaredad7's answer already more-or-less covers this, but... I think you're over-thinking. "Chosen" just means God had a plan. Also, the creed doesn't say Jesus was "begotten from eternity" but "begotten *before all worlds*", i.e. God knew His plan before He started Creating. But maybe that's just me over-reading your well known Unitarianism into the question , where actually Jesus' "begottenness" is irrelevant and the question is really whether God's plan of Salvation existed eternally or had some temporal starting point.

Comment: @Matthew Yes, it certainly ties into questions of God's plan - was there a point where an eternally begotten Son *wasn't* chosen becomes a relevant question.

Comment: @Matthew So here I suppose we get a question "Chosen as what?" Whether the 'choosing' has to do with being the unique Son, or whether it has to do with being the Christ as distinguished from being the unique Son, say.

Comment: Ultimately, I think you're asking us to explain how causality works when there is no universe, and thus, no time. Which is a terribly fascinating question, but I'm not sure anyone other than God is qualified to answer. 

Comment: @Matthew Another mystery! ;)

Comment: A good answer to this question should also apply to Luke 23:35, which uses a similar expression: "*Christ, the chosen of God*", using the same Greek word.

Comment: To supplement jaredad7's metaphysical answer, another line of explanation maybe more congenial to you is the narrative purpose of the Gospel of Luke, and thus what "chosen" would have meant for the audience.  A book I'm skimming through [The Son of God in the Roman World: Divine Sonship in its Social and Political Context](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0199933650) is relevant to your Q here: Chapter 1: Divine Sonship Before Nicea - Biblical Scholarship on "Son of God") has excellent review of 4 clusters of meaning, Chapter 5: Begotten and Adopted Sons of God - Before and after Nicea), etc.

Answer (score 6):

Your premise about choosing is inaccurate. Or, at least, it doesn't apply universally to all Christian views of God, even all traditional Christian views of God. Under a Boethian understanding of God's perspective, God's choosing would never be part of a chronology, but totally separate from any temporal sequence of events. This is because all moments are eternally present to God. He exists in what is commonly called today the "eternal now."

Anyone who holds to the Boethian view would easily answer your question by saying that the Son was chosen eternally, rather than being in some sense initially "not chosen" and later "chosen."

Comment: +1 So on this view, 'chosen' is being used in an almost completely unique sense here, like 'begotten' is used?

Comment: Yes. In fact, for many Catholics (any Thomists, and probably some non-thomists), all of the actions and qualities predicated of God are used only in an analogous sense, and are thus completely unique to God alone.